# Returning an empty String

Tags: java

I'm calling a textField box with input in the box via a button but it is returning an empty string. Here is the same code;

```
Panel Class
    //creates the textField
    panel1.add(text.getfname());







Class TextBoxes 

public JTextField getfname(){   
    JTextField fname = new JTextField(80);
    fname.setBounds( 100, 100, 150, 20 );
    fname.setSize(200,30);
    return fname;

    }
```

And class where the textField is called

```
TextBoxes text = new TextBoxes();
String fname = text.getfname().getText();
```

I'm just a little puzzled

Comment: Don't feel, but you are not setting any text to textfield right? So obviously it will return empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're creating a *new* `JTextField` within `getfname`:

```
JTextField fname = new JTextField(80);
fname.setBounds( 100, 100, 150, 20 );
fname.setSize(200,30);
return fname;
```

What content would you *expect* that to have?

I suspect you really intended to return an *existing* `JTextField` - presumably one which has been displayed to a user.

I would consider changing the method to return a `String` instead of the text box itself, too:

```
public String getFirstName() {
     // Or whatever the existing text box variable is called
    return firstNameField.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're always creating a new textfield.

Unless you *put* the textfield somewhere, and enter data in it, it will always be empty.